# Replace array items after an index

Tags: arrays, julia

Let

```
A=[x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3,y4]
```

I want to replace everything after `y1` in the arrays `A`:

```
A=[x1,x2,x3,y1,y1,y1,y1]
```

I tried

```
for i in eachindex(A)
   if A[i]==y1
      for j in i:length(A)
        A[j]=y1
      end
   end 
end
```

but it seems complicate, is there any other way to do it simple?

Comment: How is this reproducible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to fix your own code instead of a different approach:

```
for i in eachindex(A)
   if A[i]==y1
      for j in i+1:lastindex(A)
        A[j]=y1
      end
      break # this is important 
   end 
end
```

The `break` statement jumps out of the current loop. It should also be very efficient. I also replaced `length(A)` with `lastindex(A)` to make it more generic, since you already use `eachindex`.

Comment: This will be fast. Perhaps the inner loop can be replaced with `@views fill!(A[i+1:lastindex(A)], y1)`

Comment: @DanGetz, does it have any specific reason not to use `end` instead of `lastindex(A)`?

Comment: @fandak `end` should be okay (was just copy-pasting from answer).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want? In the example I assume that your `y1` is `1`.

```
julia> A = [5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 7, 8]
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 4
 3
 1
 2
 7
 8

julia> loc = findfirst(==(1), A)
4

julia> isnothing(A) || (A[loc:end] .= 1);

julia> A
7-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 4
 3
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: If `findfirst('s', "first") == 4`, why can't we have `findfirst(1,A)==4`? It seems natural. Was there any reason this specialized case not implemented?

Comment: `let found = false ; [ found || x==1 ? ( found = true ; 1 ) : x for x in A] end` also works (just adding diversity)

Comment: can you add it in answer? @DanGetz

Comment: @DanGetz because for searching in strings there is a fixed set of things you can look for. If you write `findfirst(x, A)` in general it would be ambiguous if `x` is a value you look for or a predicate function to apply.